# Vertica: how to know what indexes a table has?

Tags: vertica

Let's say I have a table in Vertica database named "my_table" and I want to run a query that will tell me what indexes exist on this table. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such things as indexes in Vertica. Each table has projections ([Physical Schema](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConceptsGuide/Components/PhysicalSchema.htm), [Working with Projections](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Projections/WorkingWithProjections.htm)).

To see what projections a table has, run the following query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM projections
WHERE anchor_table_name = 'my_table';
```